# How to count duplicate values only once in a column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm working on Power BI report and I have a table which contains list of Organisations and the roles within each of the organisation as below. I would like to count the "Total_Role" under each "ID". How can I achieve this, any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm quite new in dax.

[image]

I'm expecting the measure should count only 1 role against each ID. So the total should be 3 not 8

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way to handle this issue through AllExcept Function in DAX
Code will be :

```
Countingsingle = CALCULATE(MAX(TABLE['Total_Role'],ALLEXCEPT(Table,Table['Orgnistation'],Table['ID'])
```

Hope it help

Comment: Thank you , I will also try the method you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in a measure:

```
TotalRole =
SUMX ( 
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Table',
        'Table'[ID],
        'Table'[Total_Role]
    ),
    'Table'[Total_Role]
)
```

Gives the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works, I think I have an issue with my data. but I got an idea how to achieve it through your helpful query.